# Webbrowser control in silverlight does not refresh the pdf content in Adobe Reader 8 & 9

Tags: pdf, silverlight-4.0, browser, controls, refresh

I hava a web browser control in my silverlight application to display pdf documents.
The problem is the content does not get refreshed even after changing the source of the web browser control.
The first pdf file that gets load is shown in place of all the other pdf links.
The problem is weird since everything works perfectly fine with Adobe Reader 7 and i face this refresh issue with Adobe Reader 8 & 9.
I dont think its anything to do with webbrowser control because html pages gets refreshed without any problem

Looking forward for any help

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
webBrowserCtrl.Document.InvokeScript("window.location.reload()");
```